# Is it bad practice when I assign pointer with new pointer without free?

Tags: c

Is it bad practice when I assign new pointer to pointer without free?

```
char **arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr)*9);

...
...

arr[5] = strdup("sys");
arr[6] = strdup("var");
arr[7] = strdup("home");
arr[8] = NULL;

arr[5] = arr[6];
arr[6] = arr[7];
arr[7] = NULL;
```

Comment: Before the assignment `arr[5] = arr[6];` you need to `free(arr[5]);` Otherwise, the pointer that was in `arr[5]` is lost forever, and that memory cannot be freed (until the program exits and the OS cleans up the mess).

Comment: Yes, but why the elided code for the part you are specifically asking about!?  Surely the actual code could have been shorter than the comment "_`// allocate and add value`_"?  Without the actual code it is not possible to tell whether you are doing anything bad.  It depends on what you actually mean by "allocate".

Comment: I missed it. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  Since that pointer you reassigned (e.g. arr[5]) is no longer accessible it's memory can't be free'd and it is a memory leak.

Comment: Does it solve the problem if I free all element and free(arr) at the end?

Comment: It won't free, since the pointer is pointing somewhere else. Free it, before changing where the pointer points to. That said, once the program finishes, everything gets freed by the OS. But if your programs runs for a long time, lots of leaks can cause problems.

Comment: I was looking for a code snippet to create a dynamic array, I found it on a blog, but after I observed it again like something was wrong but I'm not sure if this is really wrong.
Ok, I get it. I will edit the code and be able to use it. Thanks :)

Comment: Added on to this, it is very helpful to use the tool [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to track down any similar memory leaks, in addition to [asan](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: Thank your suggestion, I will try to install it

Comment: And I'm sorry for my English 